# How to authenticate private repos in package.json

Tags: git, npm, npm-package

I have a private repo in package.json before npm install I changes the repo link from

```
git+http://gitserver.company.in/React-Components/react-dialogs.git
change to with the help of sed
git+http://username:auth_token@gitserver.company.in/React-Components/react-dialogs.git
```

Which works file but the react-dialogs repo there is a package json which also has a private repo which has to be authenticated.
So I receive this obvious error.

These steps works in automation so no manual thing can't be done.

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t http://gitserver.company.in/React-Components/calender-field.git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
npm ERR! fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://gitserver.company.in/React-Components/calender-field.git/'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

Comment: Can you use git+ssh instead of git+http scheme?

Comment: Off Course not the build process runs in a pod which is created in automation just for build process.
So there is no way to manual stuff because for ssh we need to add keys and stuff.